# How do I set the background-color of buttons in the sass version of foundation?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'd like to change the background colour of a button style in the foundation version of sass.

Looking at the source of _buttons.scss, I can see that there is a mixin called 'button-style'. Within it, 'background-colour' is given the value of the variable $bg.

However, there is no definition of $bg withing the mixin or even that file.

I could just remove '$bg' from that line, and add a custom colour, but that's a dirty solution that will lead to problems.

Where is $bg defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same confusion myself. Thing is $bg is being assigned a value in the mixin declaration

`@mixin button-style($bg:$primary-color...)`

and here

```
@mixin button($padding:$button-med, $bg:$primary-color,...) {
 ...
  @include button-style($bg, $radius, $disabled);
}
```

You can replace the $primary-color here but it will affect ALL your buttons. 
A better idea is to create a new button class and call this mixin with your preferred color as a parameter

```
.new-button{
  @include button-base;
  @include button-size;
  @include button-style(your-preferred-color);
}
```

Compile this and use .new-button class

Comment: to customize size use: `@include button-size($button-tny)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way

`.new-button {
  $primary-color: #whatevercolor;
  @include button;
}`

Since you are setting the `$primary-color` in the declaration, the scope is contained within that declaration.

Comment: I didn't know you can scope variables like this in sass..does this work for you? I think this is a beautiful solution

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$bg` in `_settings.scss` does not work as it is being assigned a value in the mixin declaration as Vinay Raghu already explained. The good news is that [a recent commit](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/5074) has been made to fix this.

When this is released in the next version of Foundation 5 the answer to the original *Where is $bg defined?* will be *In `_settings.scss` by changing `$button-bg`*.